# Encoder to msrle format with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, video-encoding, file-format

I need to create some files for an old windows API, for a video playback. The native windows files which works with this old API have the format of MSRLE. They are used as small animations during copy, move, etc.
My belowed FFMPEG program has a decoder for those files, but not an encoder.

I would like to convert small AVI files to MSRLE format, preferably using ffmpeg under Linux. Did I overlooked some function/option with FFMPEG?
How to build/compile FFMPEG to have the functionality which allows me to encode video files in MSRLE format?